# Is there any study of Mathematical systems that has the same n-binary operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I am currently studying Groups and Rings. Groups and Rings are types of Mathematical System.
Now, imagine an ordered (n+1)-tuple (X, *₁,*₂,...,*ₙ) where X is a non-empty set and *ᵢ is a binary operation on X, i = 1,2,3, ... ,n.
My question is that is there a term for a Mathematical system where all the binary operations are the same?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: [Here is what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auDh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a structure $\langle X, *_1, \dots, *_n \rangle$ where $*_1 = \dots = *_n$ and $n >0$, is equivalent to considering the structure $\langle X, *_1 \rangle$.
So in most cases there is little need to give a special term to this situation.